# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException in SocialAuth (Spring)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, socialauth

I am trying to set up [SocialAuth](http://code.google.com/p/socialauth), defined by the website as:

> "Java Library for registration and authentication through Google,
>   Yahoo, Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn, FourSquare, MySpace and other Open
>   ID providers"

It is supposed to work like on http://opensource.brickred.com/socialauthdemo/

I have set up the workspace exactly as described on the page http://code.google.com/p/socialauth/wiki/SpringSample with a few differences (version etc). My library content is as below:

- aopalliance-1.0.jar
- commons-codec.jar
- commons-httpclient-3.1.jar
- commons-logging-1.1.jar
- json-20080701.jar openid4java.jar
- org.springframework.aop-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
- org.springframework.asm-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
- org.springframework.aspects-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
- org.springframework.beans-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
- org.springframework.context-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
- org.springframework.context.support-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
- org.springframework.core-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
- org.springframework.expression-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
- org.springframework.instrument-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
- org.springframework.instrument.tomcat-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
- org.springframework.jdbc-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
- org.springframework.jms-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
- org.springframework.orm-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
- org.springframework.oxm-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
- org.springframework.test-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
- org.springframework.transaction-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
- org.springframework.web-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
- org.springframework.web.portlet-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
- org.springframework.web.servlet-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
- org.springframework.web.struts-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
- socialauth-2.0-beta3.jar socialauth-spring-2.0-beta2.jar

When I run Tomcat Server, I am getting org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException.
Complete log [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/36999182/Log.txt).

I'm a novice to Spring framework, and therefore a bit lost in the error message.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

TIA,
James

---

## EDIT

**The above problem is gone for now. However I'm getting a new one when I hit the url:**
http://localhost:8080/springsocialauthdemo/socialAuth.do?id=facebook

> Aug 26, 2011 10:20:25 AM
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
>   WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI
>   [/springsocialauthdemo/socialAuth.do] in DispatcherServlet with name
>   'springsocialauthdemo'

Probably it's too lame a problem, but I just posted it while I'm working on it.
Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 2):

Look at the bottom of the stacktrace - you are missing [cglib](http://cglib.sourceforge.net/) on the classpath, and you need to for a scoped proxy of a concrete class - add it.

Comment: It's there in root-context.xml, just like you can see on http://code.google.com/p/socialauth/wiki/SpringSample

Comment: <bean id="socialAuthTemplate" class="org.brickred.socialauth.spring.bean.SocialAuthTemplate" scope="session">
        <aop:scoped-proxy/>
    </bean>

Comment: Thanks Bozho, this error is gone for now. However, I'm across a new one. Please check the edit above.